# How to post to json sever

Tags: reactjs

tried posting to json db but only gets the Id in the json server with no postdate, posttitle, postdesc and image. i dont know i am doing wrong.

I would also like to like to update a post and then should be redirected to the homepage after updating the post.

I had tried using Redirect, useHistory and then useNavigate ffrom react-router-dom but still isnt working

```
      import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
      import "./write.css";
      import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
      
              export default function Write() {
                const [image, setImage] = useState();
                const [posttitle, setPostTitle] = useState("");
                const [postdesc, setPostDesc] = useState("");
                const [postdate, setPostDate] = useState("20/30/2020");
                // const [postDate, setPostDate] = useState("");
              
                const navigate = useNavigate();
              
                //==============================================================//
                //Publishing or posting a post to the json server
                const formSubmit = (e)=> {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  const docs = {
                    image,
                    posttitle,
                    postdate,
                    postdesc,
                  };
              
                  fetch("http://localhost:8005/posts", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { contentType: "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify(docs),
                  }).then(() => {
                    navigate.push("/home");
                  });
              
                  console.log(docs);
                }
              
                //===============================================================//
              
     // const { id } = useParams(); not working
    // getting the id of the post to be edited using window.location.href
    const url = window.location.href;
    const id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
    // //editing/Updating post data in the json-server file
    // function editBtn() {
    //   fetch("http://localhost:8005/posts/" + id, {
    //     method: "PUT",
    //     body: JSON.stringify(),
    //     headers: {
    //       contentType: "application.json",
    //     },
    //   });
    // }        
            
          
              return (
                  <div className="write">
                    <form className="writeform" onSubmit={formSubmit}>
                      <div>
                        <input />
                        date here
                      </div>
              
                      <div className="image_container">
                        {image && (
                          <div>
                            <img
                              className="writeimage"
                              alt="postimage"
                              src={URL.createObjectURL(image)}
                              onChange={(e) => {
                                setImage(e.target.src);
                              }}
                            />
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </div>
                      <div className="writeformgroup">
                        <label htmlFor="fileinput">
                          <i className="writeicon fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="fileinput"
                          type="file"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setImage(e.target.files[0]);
                          }}
                          style={{ display: "none" }}
                        />
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          // value={postTitle}
                          className="writeinput"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setPostTitle(e.target.value);
                          }}
                          autoFocus
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="writeformgroup">
                        <textarea
                          // value={postDesc}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setPostDesc(e.target.value);
                          }}
                          type="text"
                          className="writeinput writetext"
                        ></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <button className="writesubmit">Publish</button>
                    </form>
                    <p>{posttitle}</p>
                  </div>
                );
          
          }
```

`//JSON DB
{

"posts": [
{
"image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/9968415/pexels-photo-9968415.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
"posttitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ",
"postdate": "20-29-2022",
"postdesc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur sequi ad eveniet necessitatibus reiciendis dolor deleniti qui mod",
"id": 1
},
{
"image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/13957041/pexels-photo-13957041.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
"posttitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ",
"postdate": "20-29-2022",
"postdesc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur sequi ad eveniet necessitatibus reiciendis dolor deleniti qui mod",
"id": 2
},
{
"image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/13715795/pexels-photo-13715795.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
"posttitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ",
"postdate": "20-29-2022",
"postdesc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur sequi ad eveniet necessitatibus reiciendis dolor deleniti qui mod",
"id": 3
},
{
"image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/13420447/pexels-photo-13420447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&lazy=load",
"posttitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ",
"postdate": "20-29-2022",
"postdesc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur sequi ad eveniet necessitatibus reiciendis dolor deleniti qui mod",
"id": 4
},
{
"image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/13950829/pexels-photo-13950829.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
"posttitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ",
"postdate": "20-29-2022",
"postdesc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur sequi ad eveniet necessitatibus reiciendis dolor deleniti qui mod",
"id": 5
},
{
"image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/11055161/pexels-photo-11055161.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
"posttitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ",
"postdate": "20-29-2022",
"postdesc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, suscipit inventore. Facilis ducimus quod ratione, fugiat temporibus, porro vitae consequuntur aspernatur sequi ad eveniet necessitatibus reiciendis dolor deleniti qui mod",
"id": 6
}
]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try useHistory for redirect issues

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

  const histroy = useHistory();

 histroy.push({ pathname: '/home' });
```

Try async /await for fetch

```
const formSubmit = async () => {
try{
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8005/posts", {
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: { contentType: "application/json" },
                  body: JSON.stringify(docs),
                });

  if(!response || !response.ok){
   throw new Error('error message');
  }

  const data = response.json();

 console.log(data);
 }catch(error){
  console.log(error);
 }
}
```

Comment: this didnt work, only seeing the id in the json server

Comment: share the back-end code

Comment: i just shared the back end code, please check the edited post